# References for endomorphism bundle and adjoint bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

I am trying to understand what are endomorphism bundle(of a vector bundle) and adjoint bundle(of a principal bundle) but could not find any references on google.

Searching  Adjoint bundle gives https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_bundle which does not really say much. But searching endomorphism bundle does not give anything.

Any reference is welcome.

Endomorphism bundle came in context when discussing about curvatures. It has been said that Curvature can be seen as section of some endomorphism bundle.

Comment: There is a general notion of associated bundle whenever you have a principal $G$-bundle and a smooth action of $G$ on a smooth manifold $F$. Are you familiar with this?

Comment: Yes yes. @AmitaiYuval

Comment: Well then you shouldn't have any problem with the adjoint bundle; it is merely the bundle associated to the principal $G$-bundle $P\to M$ and the adjoint action $G\to\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval yes that is true. I know only that definition and nothing else.. But just that definition with out further steps seems to be of less use.

Comment: As it turns out if $G=GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $P\to M$ is the frame bundle of the vector bundle $E\to M$, then the adjoint bundle is isomorphic to $\mathrm{End}(E)$, the endomorphism bundle of $E$. How much do you know about this latter one?

Comment: Absolutely nothing :) you started with a vector bundle $E\rightarrow M$ and you considered frame bundle of this bundle which is $P\rightarrow M$. Structur egroup of this bundle is $Gl(n,\mathbb{R}$ so, we can talk about the adjoint bundle of $P\rightarrow M$ and you are calling this bundle to be the endomorphism bundle of $E\rightarrow M$? Is that it’s?? I have not seen this before,

Answer (score 7):

Here is a short answer regarding the endomorphism bundle of a vector bundle $E\to M$. The fiber of $\mathrm{End}(E)$ at a point $p\in M$ consists of all linear maps $E_p\to E_p$. This fiber is clearly a vector space. Furthermore, if $E$ is trivial in the open set $U\subset M$, then so is $\mathrm{End}(E)$. Hence, $\mathrm{End}(E)$ is indeed a vector bundle, and a section of this bundle is to be understood as a smooth family of linear maps $E_p\to E_p$ for $p\in M$.

If you like operations on vector bundles, you may like the natural identification$$\mathrm{End}(E)=E\otimes E^*.$$

**Edit:** Let us see how the endomorphism bundle arises naturally when playing with curvature. Let $E\to M$ be a vector bundle equipped with a linear connection $\nabla$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector fields on $M,$ and let $s$ be a section of $E$. We define $$R(X,Y)(s):=\nabla_X\nabla_Ys-\nabla_Y\nabla_Xs-\nabla_{[X,Y]}s.$$ Then one can show that $R$ is in fact tensorial in all its arguments. Moreover, as $R$ is clearly anti-symmetric in $X$ and $Y$, it is a $2$-form on $M$ with values in the vector bundle $\mathrm{End}(E)$. This $R$ is called the curvature (or curvature form) of $\nabla$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give some text reference for this or some other concept where we use this endomorphism bundle.

Comment: @cello I edited my answer and added the relation to curvature. This is more or less the only setting in which I ever worked with the endomorphism bundle.

Comment: I do not really understand the words “ $2$ form on $M$ with values in $End(E)$”.. I can see that $R: X(M)\times X(M)\times \Gamma(E)\rightarrow \Gamma(E)$... I do not see what it means to say some form with values Ina vector bundle... I know what it means to say some form with values in Lie algebra,.. connection form in case of principal $G$ bundles (as in Kobayashi Nomizu) is $M\rightarrow \Lambda_{\mathfrak{g}TM$ with $m\mapsto \omega(m):T_mP\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$.. here $\mathfrak{g}$ is liealgebra of $G$

Comment: $M\rightarrow \Lambda_{\mathfrak{g}} TM$

Comment: @cello This may help:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_differential_form